# Timers and Forms not closing when method called

Tags: c#, methods, timer

I have three seperate timers that call a method in each of their _Tick. This method works fine, as intended, but within it is an if statement which checks to see if two values are either < or > than a number:

```
if ((x < y) || (x > z))
{

}
```

and within this statement, I want to stop those three times, show a message box and dispose the form. This is the code I'm using:

```
if ((x < yArray[0]) || (x > yArray[1]))
{
   frmFooBar barFoo = new frmFooBar();
   barFoo.tmrOne.Stop();
   barFoo.tmrTwo.Stop();
   barFoo.tmrThree.Stop();
   MessageBox.Show(GlobalVariables.aVariable+ " is dead.");
   barFoo.Dispose();
}
```

The conditional works fine, as when either statement is true, I'll get a MessageBox popup every tick. The problem I'm having is that none of those form functions are working. tmrOne,Two keep running, and the form does not close.

I'm still new to C# so maybe my problem is obvious, but any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing this in your method:

```
frmFooBar barFoo = new frmFooBar(); 
barFoo.tmrOne.Stop(); 
barFoo.tmrTwo.Stop();
```

This creates a **new instance of frmFooBar**, and has no effect on the instance that's already running.

If this is happening within the tick event of a timer on your form, you'll want to use "this", since that will be the currently running form:

```
this.tmrOne.Stop();
this.tmrTwo.Stop();
```

That way, you're stopping the timers on the currently running form.

Answer (score 0):

to Close the form you need to use form.Close();   you can use  this.Close();   if you want to close the form you'r in.
to stop the timer use the Timer.Enabled = false;
Hope it help
Amit

Comment: oh,  there is a chance you are using global verbs? cause then you need to pass the form with the timers to the form you are calling this method from..

Comment: if not, just call directly to the timers and the close method without the 'FormName'.Timer.Stop()